# should i update log records or insert only

Tags: sql, database, logging, locking

In the context of logging operations by applications, what do you think are the best practices for updating progress from databese perspective? In my experience, it is best to only insert new records with new statuses into the log table in the database. Unfortunately, I often see how junior programmers try to update the statuses in the existing logs and act only on one entry with a unique process id. This leads to deadlocks by page locks or multithreading if they are scanning through different filters. Then you need to introduce proper lock management to such solutions, which further complicates the logic and such people later have a complete problem with understanding the behavior of the database.

So is a plain insert the only simplest and maintainable solution, or do you know of other simpler approaches?

Thanks in advance for Your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

A log record is, almost by definition, a record of a point in time. If you update it then you’ve lost the record of that point in time. Therefore log records should never be updated, they should be insert only